# Working with strings using pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers

So hello guys, its my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void writeDown(string*t)
{
    for (int i = 0; *(t+i)!=NULL; i++)
    {
        cout << *(t+i) <<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string t;
    getline(cin, t);
    string *wsk = &t;
    writeDown(wsk);
    return 0;
}
```

So I simply insert a string, and program should `cout<<` every single char from it in a new line. But here is what pops out:

`binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

What am I doing wrong?

Btw. I am working in VS 2013 for Win Desktop (btw. vol.2 - is it a good environment for C++ coding? - got 2015, but it's to slow on my laptop)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to treat `std::string*` like it's a `char*`. That's not how it works, they are very different things.

Comment: Awkay, maybe, so what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: If `std::string` is analogous to `const char*`, to what would `std::string*` be analogous?

Comment: @Frynio if my answer worked for you, will you be kind enough to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that code is bad in so many levels, but just to keep it simple and answer your question I would probably use iterators. Forget about that old C style if you are using C++.

Try this:

```
void writeDown(const string & t)
{
    for (string::const_iterator it = t.begin();
        it != t.end();
        ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that `writeDown` no longer takes a pointer as parameter but a constant reference to the string you want to print.

You will have to change your main to call `writeDown`:

```
string t;
getline(cin, t);
writeDown(t);
```

If you insist on using the "array" method you would have to use it like this, but ...

```
void writeDown(const string & t)
{
    for (int i = 0; t.c_str()[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        cout << t.c_str()[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the same thing (by "the same" I mean speed) when I use `asterix &` or `*` as a parameter?

Comment: @Frynio Premature optimization is the root of stupid. Concentrate on writing code that's easy to understand and maintain then optimize based on the results of profiling.

Comment: Thank you. I would always do some sort of unimportant things, focusing on them, not on my main goal